# Case Routing: assigning queue as Case OwnerId-

Tags: apex, trigger, case

I have an issue for a case routing process. My aim is to route a case upon creation to a specific queue based on different attributes.

I am taking three attributes Product Org, Product and Account on Asset and Asset is selected form Case for now. Based on their combination we send them to a specific queue or a user(for user-- I implemented by using a checkbox field)

I created a custom object Routing Attributes for this which stores the three attributes and the Queue and User values.

The challenge I face here is shown in the below picture.

[image]
   From what we have here, the case is being improperly routed when it finds the last two rows. Here except the product attribute all other values are same. So for Ra-00000003 the queue Case Routing 1 is not being assigned.

Is there a way to avoid this. Please help!!!!!!

```
trigger routingTest on Case (before insert,before update) {


List<Id> productOrgIds = new List<Id>();
List<Id> ProductIds = new List<Id>();
List<Id> assetIds = new List<Id>();

for(Case c : trigger.new){   
  assetIds.add(c.assetId);
}
map<Id,Asset> assetMap = new Map<Id,Asset>([select id,Product1__c,Product_Org1__c,AccountId from Asset where id In: assetIds]); 
Set<Id> QIds = new Set<Id>();

List<QueueSobject> listofQueues = [select id,QueueId,Queue.Name from QueueSObject];
Map<String,Id> mapQNameWithIds = new Map<String , Id>();
for(QueueSobject so : listOfQueues){
    mapQNameWithIds.put(so.queue.name,so.queueId);
}

List<Routing_Attribute__c> attriblist=[select id,Product_Org__c,Products__c,Queue_Name__c,Account__c,Queue_ID__c,UserName__c,Assign_To_User__c from Routing_Attribute__c ];//new 
     Map<Id,Product_Org__c> mapProductOrgs = new Map<Id,Product_Org__c>([select id,name from Product_Org__c ]);
     Map<Id,Product2> mapProducts = new Map<Id,Product2>([select id,name from Product2 ]);
     Map<Id,Account> mapAccounts = new Map<Id,Account>([select id,name from Account]);



   for(Case cs : Trigger.New)
      {

         for(Routing_Attribute__c rat : attriblist)
              {

               if((assetMap.get(cs.AssetId).Product_Org1__c==rat.Product_Org__c)  && (rat.products__c !=null && rat.Products__c.contains( mapProducts.get(assetMap.get(cs.AssetId).Product1__c).name) || rat.Products__c==null) && (rat.Account__c!=null && rat.Account__c.contains( mapAccounts.get(assetMap.get(cs.AssetId).AccountId).name) || rat.Account__c==null ))  
            {
            if(rat.Assign_To_User__c==true && rat.UserName__c!=null)
            {

                cs.ownerId=rat.UserName__c;
            }
            else{
                if(mapQNameWithIds.get(rat.Queue_Name__c)!=null)
                    cs.ownerId=mapQNameWithIds.get(rat.Queue_Name__c);
                }

           }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem because the product value is empty? Or something else?

Comment: The queue must be assigned even if the product value is null based on the other two attributes. for my second and third record I have both Product org and Account as same. But one record has a null value for Product and other has a value. So when I use the for loop for routing attribute records the record with the null product value gets checked and queue is assigned, next the record that has a product values gets checked and the queue specified for this combination is being re-assigned to the same case. please refer to the above code where we have the for loop for case and routing attribute

Answer (score 2):

Ace --

I might suggest you build a composite String key in Apex for every decision operand field of `Routing_Attribute__c` - use the string value 'null' for empty fields - then create a lookup map whose key is the composite key built above and whose value is the corresponding `Routing_Attribute__c` object

Then, as you process each Case, construct a lookup key using the same logic as was used to build the reference map. A simple

```
Routing_Attribute__c rat = ratKeyToRatMap.get(lookupKey);
cs.ownerId = rat.assign_to_user__c
              ? rat.user_name__c
              : rat_queue_name__c;
```

should then do the trick.

In other words, remove all the complex if logic and just do simple lookup into a single apex map.

Comment: I started to devise a similar answer, but there is a problem - what seems to be more than one product possible for the combination of the other two fields, i.e. you could get a key that looked like this: ProductOrg | Product1 | Product2 | Account or ProductOrg | Product1 | Account.

Comment: I suppose you could build up a Map that had one of each of the products for each ProductOrd - Account combo, but it might get big... Still, this is probably the best solution for the job. Implementing it might be tricky though.

Comment: @CaspNZ, true enough hence my 'suggestion' as to an approach rather than writing all the code. The multiple products are delimited and could be sorted before creating a synthetic key. I only wish SFDC would provide a way to use point-and-click to write the equivalent of Lead/Case/Territory assignment rules but for custom, rule-based application problems so the developer didn't need to come up with either their own rules engine or artifices such as I proposed

Comment: Crop1645, I was looking at this from a diff perspective. I am devising a method, will post that once I see it works along with the code. I would also like to try your suggestion.